# Shift node text in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I need to display two lines of text at a node using tikz. The code I am using is:

```
    \documentclass{book}

    \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[black, -{Stealth[length=3mm]}]    (1,5) -- (3,5) 
                node[right, green, anchor = south west] {first language text} 
                node[right, blue, anchor = north west] {second language text};      
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

This code produces this:

[image]

Which has one problem, the vertical distance between the two lines is too big. How can I make this distance smaller without having to make a new node?

Comment: Change their `inner ysep` value or use one node with a line break (`align=left` as an option and ``\\`` between the lines) or any other LaTeX way to have two lines (say, a `tabular` environment ). Colors can be changed inside the node text with the usual ways, don't need TikZ for that. You can always `yshift` both nodes together or set values `text depth` (for the upper) and `text height` (lower) to overwrite the automatic sizing.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, Thanks Qrrbrbirlbel, inner ysep solved it perfectly.